# Using fill() with a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(X = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A8", "A9", "A9"),
             Y = c(31, 52, 45, 86, NA, 50, 93, 85, 59, NA, 85, NA),
             Z = c(70, 64, 51, 38, 18, NA, 76, 54, NA, 69, NA, 96),
             D = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2))
> df
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   X         Y     Z     D
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1       31    70     1
 2 A2       52    64     1
 3 A3       45    51     1
 4 A4       86    38     1
 5 A5       NA    18     2
 6 A5       50    NA     2
 7 A6       93    76     1
 8 A7       85    54     1
 9 A8       59    NA     2
10 A8       NA    69     2
11 A9       85    NA     2
12 A9       NA    96     2
```

The column `X` has duplicate values that sometimes repeat twice. Column `D` is measuring those occurances. Column `Y` and `Z` have some scores. I want those scores to repeat within those duplicated observations within column `X`. I tried using `fill()` method and my output is below

```
df %>%
  filter(D == 1) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
              filter(D != 1) %>%
              fill(c("Y", "Z"), .direction = "downup")
  )

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   X         Y     Z     D
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1       31    70     1
 2 A2       52    64     1
 3 A3       45    51     1
 4 A4       86    38     1
 5 A6       93    76     1
 6 A7       85    54     1
 7 A5       50    18     2
 8 A5       50    18     2
 9 A8       59    18     2
10 A8       59    69     2
11 A9       85    69     2
12 A9       85    96     2
```

However, whatever `.direction` option I use, I cannot seem to get correct numbers. For example in the above output, for `A9`, `Z` should be repeating `96` twice. Same issue is with `A8`.

My desired output is below

```
   X         Y     Z     D
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1       31    70     1
 2 A2       52    64     1
 3 A3       45    51     1
 4 A4       86    38     1
 5 A6       93    76     1
 6 A7       85    54     1
 7 A5       50    18     2
 8 A5       50    18     2
 9 A8       59    69     2
10 A8       59    69     2
11 A9       85    96     2
12 A9       85    96     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  mutate(across(Y:Z, ~ first(na.omit(.))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   X [9]
   X         Y     Z     D
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1       31    70     1
 2 A2       52    64     1
 3 A3       45    51     1
 4 A4       86    38     1
 5 A5       50    18     2
 6 A5       50    18     2
 7 A6       93    76     1
 8 A7       85    54     1
 9 A8       59    69     2
10 A8       59    69     2
11 A9       85    96     2
12 A9       85    96     2
```

You could also use `fill` like below, but in my experience this can be quite slow:

```
df %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  fill(Y, Z, .direction = 'downup')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use group_by and mutate to change the values of the NAs to the other one in the group

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(X) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Y = dplyr::case_when(
      is.na(Y) ~ Y[!is.na(Y)],
      TRUE ~ Y),
    Z = dplyr::case_when(
      is.na(Z) ~ Z[!is.na(Z)],
      TRUE ~ Z))
```